# How to get data row by date wise where i pass date picker's date and store data as long format date

Tags: sqlite

When i call getAllInvoice(Date date) to get observable invoice list by passing date from date picker but it's return empty list please help how to get invoice observable list passing date picker's date where i store date as long format in database that example i provided below.

```
public VBox getBody() {
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setPrefWidth(width);
    datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(datePicker.getValue().getYear(),datePicker.getValue().getMonthValue(),datePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth());


    ListView<String> invoiceListView = new ListView<>();
    invoiceListView.setPrefWidth(width);
    invoiceListView.setPrefHeight(550);

    ObservableList<Invoice> invoiceObservableList = connection.getAllInvoice(Date.valueOf(datePicker.getValue()));

    datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        invoiceObservableList.clear();
        invoiceObservableList.addAll(connection.getAllInvoice(Date.valueOf(datePicker.getValue())));
    });

    ListChangeListener<Invoice> listener = new ListChangeListener<Invoice>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Invoice> c) {
            ObservableList<String> invoiceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (Invoice invoice : invoiceObservableList) {
                Customer customer = connection.getCustomerById(invoice.getCustomerId());
                invoiceList.add("#" + invoice.getId() + " - " + customer.getName() + " (" + customer.getNumber() + ")");
            }
            invoiceListView.setItems(invoiceList);
        }
    };

    invoiceObservableList.addListener(listener);

    ObservableList<String> invoiceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (Invoice invoice : invoiceObservableList) {
        Customer customer = connection.getCustomerById(invoice.getCustomerId());
        invoiceList.add("#" + invoice.getId() + " - " + customer.getName() + " (" + customer.getNumber() + ")");
    }
    invoiceListView.setItems(invoiceList);

    VBox invoicePreview = new VBox();//addMe
    invoicePreview.setPrefWidth(360);
    invoicePreview.setPrefHeight(560);
    invoicePreview.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //invoicePreview.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
    //invoicePreview.setPadding(new Insets(15));

    invoiceListView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            invoicePreview.getChildren().clear();
            invoicePreview.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            Invoice invoice = invoiceObservableList.get(invoiceListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
            InvoicePreview preview = new InvoicePreview(invoice,sizer.getValue(100));
            invoicePreview.getChildren().add(preview.printPreview());
        }
    });

    Label massage = new Label("Please select invoice first.");
    massage.setFont(new Font(invoiceWidth*5/100));
    invoicePreview.getChildren().add(massage);

    VBox leftVBox = new VBox(datePicker, invoiceListView);
    leftVBox.setSpacing(5);

    HBox mainBody = new HBox(leftVBox,invoicePreview);
    mainBody.setSpacing(5);


    VBox root = new VBox(mainBody);
    root.setId("body");
    return root;
}
```

and this is the Connection class's getAllInvoice(Date date) method that return observable invoice list,

```
public ObservableList<Invoice> getAllInvoice(Date date) {
    long longDate = date.getTime();
    ObservableList<Invoice> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INVOICE + " WHERE " + INVOICE_DATE + " LIKE \'"+longDate+"\'";
    System.out.println(query);
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DATA_BASE);

        Statement state = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = state.executeQuery(query);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            list.add(new Invoice(resultSet.getInt(INVOICE_ID), resultSet.getInt(INVOICE_USER_ID), resultSet.getInt(INVOICE_CUSTOMER_ID), resultSet.getLong(INVOICE_DATE)));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return list;
}
```

datadase file like as:

```
"id" "uId" "cusId" "date"
-------------------------------
"3" "1" "4" "1524636334412"
"4" "1" "4" "1524636355419"
"5" "1" "3" "1524636411858"
"6" "1" "3" "1524637462701"
"7" "1" "4" "1524638110920"
```

how can i get data passing Date as a argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want records for the same date (day of the month of the year) as the date passed (long) then you could use :-

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice 
WHERE date / 86400000  = <your_date> / 86400000
```

- `<your_date>` being the date passed

This is stripping of the milliseconds (i.e. divide by 1000), then stripping of the seconds (i.e divide by another 60), then stripping off the minutes (i.e. divide by another 60) and then stripping of the hours (divide by 24)

i.e. **1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400000**

Based upon your example data then (where 1524636334412 is the datetime of the first row):-

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice 
WHERE date / 86400000  = 1524636334412 / 86400000
```

results in :-

[image]

As such you could change :-

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INVOICE + " WHERE " + INVOICE_DATE + " LIKE \'"+longDate+"\'";
```

to be

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INVOICE + " WHERE " + INVOICE_DATE + " / 86400000 = " + longDate + " / 86400000";
```